# Spring Boot:Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm working on my "Edit.html".
There is a form on this page and the page is for editing information on existing page.
I used the same "Post" method for many sites and had no errors.
But I don't know why I'm getting following error at this time.

My controller:

```
    @PostMapping("editKursInfo")
    public String editKursInfo(
        @Valid @ModelAttribute("edit") Kurs kurs) 
    {
        data.saveKurs(kurs);
        return "redirect:/editKursInfo";
    }
```

Html
（In order to look convenient, I deleted the relevant HTML layout code）:

```
           <form action="editKursInfo" method="POST" th:object="${edit}">
           <span th:text="${kurs.kursName}" id="kursNameSpan" style=" display: none;"></span>                          
           <td align="left" >Kurs Name</td>
           <td>
           <input th:field="*{kursName}"                                   
           type="text"
           align="left"                                
           class="form-control"
           style="width:250px;"   
           placeholder="Bitte geben Sie Ihren Vornamen ein"
           th:errorclass="is-invalid"
           id="kursNameInput"
           value=""/><br>
           <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('kursName')}" th:errors="*{kursName}" class="invalid-feedback">          </div>                                  
           </form>
```

The error:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your endpoint editKursInfo has to support both post and get (due to redirection)

```
@RequestMapping(value="/editKursInfo", method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET })
```

or you can set response status to 307

```
 public String editKursInfo(
        @Valid @ModelAttribute("edit") Kurs kurs, HttpServletRequest request)    
 request.setAttribute(
      View.RESPONSE_STATUS_ATTRIBUTE, HttpStatus.TEMPORARY_REDIRECT);
```

Comment: I have GET method already: `@GetMapping("/editKursInfo/{id}")
 ` and now have problem with POST

Comment: then your redirection is not good because de {id} has to be present if not it will resolde to the post

Comment: maybe the id must come from the save of kurs then you can do `Kurs savedKurs=data.saveKurs(kurs);
        return "redirect:/editKursInfo/"+savedKurs.getId(); `

Comment: also be careful with relative paths `@PostMapping("editKursInfo")` and `@PostMapping("/editKursInfo")` what is your class @RequestMapping?